# laravel-phpexcel , getCalculatedValue() returns int 0

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

I'v been struggling for days now with this issue.
I have an xls file, containing multiple sheets,  with functions on it. 
What i'm trying to do is to insert values at the first sheet, and then retrieve the result from the second one, but the result i'm getting is 0.

This is the code i'v written

```
    $fileType = 'Excel5';
    $fileName = storage_path().'/penssion_simulator_file/test2.xls';

    // Read the file
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

    echo "Start loading file:</br>";
    echo date('H:i:s d/m/Y')."</br>";
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);
    echo "End of loading file:</br>";
    echo date('H:i:s d/m/Y')."</br>";

    PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)->disableCalculationCache();
    PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)->clearCalculationCache();

    echo "Start setting values to file:</br>";
    echo date('H:i:s d/m/Y')."</br>";
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('B7', (string)date('d/m/Y'))
        ->setCellValue('B8', (string)'30/05/1984')
        ->setCellValue('B9', (string)'01/05/2013')
        ->setCellValue('B10', (integer)20000)
        ->setCellValue('B11', (string)'ללא בן זוג וילדים (לצורכי ביטוח)')
        ->setCellValue('B12', (float)5.5)
        ->setCellValue('B13', (float)6.0)
        ->setCellValue('B14', (float)8.33)
        ->setCellValue('B15', '-')
        ->setCellValue('B16', (string)'גבר')
        ->setCellValue('B17', (integer)0)
        ->setCellValue('B18', (integer)0)
        ->setCellValue('B19', (string)'עתיר חיסכון')
        ->setCellValue('B20', (float)6.0)
        ->setCellValue('B21', (float)0.25)
        ->setCellValue('B22', (integer)67)
        ->setCellValue('B23', (string)'כן')
        ->setCellValue('B24', (string)'לא');

    echo "End of setting values to file:</br>";
    echo date('H:i:s d/m/Y')."</br>";

    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
    echo "Value of cell B6 on sheet 1: ".($objWorksheet->getCell('B6')->getCalculatedValue())."</br>";

    // $value = $this->getCellValue($objWorksheet,'B3');

    // echo "</br>This is the value og cell B3: ".$value."</br>";

    // PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->writeDebugLog = true;
    // $this->testFormula($objWorksheet,'B3');

    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    echo "Value of cell B7 on sheet 0: ".($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B7')->getValue())."</br>";




    echo date('H:i:s d/m/Y')."</br>";
    // Change the file
    die('FIN');
```

And those are the outputs that i'm printing:

**Start loading file:**
09:03:27 28/01/2015.
**End of loading file:**
09:04:26 28/01/2015.
**Start setting values to file:**
09:04:26 28/01/2015.
**End of setting values to file:**
09:04:26 28/01/2015
**Value of cell B6 on sheet 1:** 0
**Value of cell B7 on sheet 0:** 28/01/2015
09:04:30 28/01/2015
FIN

I'm using laravel as i mentioned at the header of this post, and the laravel-phpexcel package.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: So what formulae are there in cell B6 of Worksheet 0 and Worksheet 1?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the formula evaluation using the function in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaker/5908357)?

Comment: Formula Value is =MAX(calc!R$1:R$65536)
Expected Value is 1037.3705039035
Parser Stack :-
Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => Cell Reference [value] => calc!R$1 [reference] => calc!R$1 ) [1] => Array ( [type] => Cell Reference [value] => calc!R$65536 [reference] => calc!R$65536 ) [2] => Array ( [type] => Binary Operator [value] => : [reference] => ) [3] => Array ( [type] => Operand Count for Function MAX() [value] => 1 [reference] => ) [4] => Array ( [type] => Function [value] => MAX( [reference] => ) ) PARSER ERROR: Use of undefined constant EOL - assumed 'EOL'

Comment: this is the second part of the debugging answer                                              
Parser Stack :-
Array ( [0] => Array ( [type] => Cell Reference [value] => calc!R$1 [reference] => calc!R$1 ) [1] => Array ( [type] => Cell Reference [value] => calc!R$65536 [reference] => calc!R$65536 ) [2] => Array ( [type] => Binary Operator [value] => : [reference] => ) [3] => Array ( [type] => Operand Count for Function MAX() [value] => 1 [reference] => ) [4] => Array ( [type] => Function [value] => MAX( [reference] => ) )

Comment: Do i need to save the file first for the formulas be affected?